# Opening router ports for SSH

Tags: linux, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to SSH to my laptop on my home from my college PC. I searched about a few ways to do it and I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749230/is-it-possible-to-ssh-between-two-different-network) what I think is the easiest way. I set up port forwarding in an Arris TG862 modem that connects to the internet and connects to my laptop via ethernet, set up my laptop to use an static IP (same as the one used on port forwarding), then I tested it by trying to connect via SSH from a netbook, which was connected to an AP which is connected to the Arris modem. SSH timed out, though.

Searching a bit more, I found a checklist related to this problem, and the first item that failed was to check whether the port 22 was open. I used `canyouseeme.org` and it returned connection timed out.

Is port 22 really closed? How do I open it? Otherwise, what else could be keeping me from connecting?

My home system is a Dell Inspiron I15-5558-D30 (service tag H5F02H2) running Debian Unstable x64. My college system are various PCs running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and some version of openSUSE. My netbook is an HP Mini 110-3110br running Debian Jessie x86.

Here's how I set up the port forwarding:

[image: Arris setup]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ClassStacker That's only for the Delete button. // The ISP most likely does not allow inbound connections. Try different ports. Also check your public IP address as reported by your router and compare it with IP checker websites, you may be subject to CGNAT.

Comment: A Google search for "arris ssh" yields some interesting results. They probably blocked the port because of that security vulnerability.

Comment: I fixed the first post, because I got my Debian version wrong. @Daniel B, I learned about and tested with GRC's Shields Up, and the following port ranges were "stealth": 2-1055, 65000-65535 and a few random ranges between 1000 and 1500. I tested 22 with some changes in the router's setup, such as with/without port triggering and with firewall enabled, which I read somewhere is required for forwarding to work. I found nothing related to NAT hairpin or similar, which I also read about somewhere. I've used the public IP as found out in websites from the beginning. And they never cease to amaze me

Comment: If you want to ssh into your laptop use some other port besides 22 to do so, that way, you won't fall into any isp port blocking.  Also do it while connected to a vpn to secure yourself